# Dropdown form submit

Tags: html, onclick, submit, onchange

i have a dropdown form but its not working when i want to submit it.
Here it is:

```
        <form name="subselect">
        <select name="menu">
        <option selected="selected" value="javascript:void(0)">Select Payment Period</option>
        <option value="http://1.com">Every 3 Months</option>
        <option value="http://2.com">Every 6 Months</option>
        <option value="http://3.com">Every 12 Months</option>
        <option value="http://4.com">Every 24 Months</option>
        </select>
        <li class="pricing_footer"><a onclick="window.document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" value="GO" class="pricing_button">Purchase</a></li>           
        </form>
```

it works like so:

```
<select name="menu" onChange="window.document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" value="GO">
```

but i want a separate button to be the submit one.

Comment: Unless I misunderstand the question, why not remove the `onChange`? That way, selecting one of the dropdowns won't trigger anything.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `button`:

```
<button>Submit</button>
```

Or an input (type=submit):

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try `window.open(url)`

or submit button change url `onsubmit`

Answer (score 0):

You can use :
input type="submit" value="Submit

And you should use: 
form action="action_page.php method="GET" 
for your further action.
If you click "Submit", the form-data will be sent to a page called "action_page.php".

details: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Comment: Please use code formatting on your code snippet in answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys!
I did the following thing, created a new script and assigned the submit button to it. I want the script to be able to open new url from the selected dropdown and it works now.

```
            <script>function purchasefunc() {
        var url=document.redirect.selection.value
        document.location.href=url
        }</script>
```

and the button

```
<a type=button value="Purchase" onClick="purchasefunc();" style="cursor: pointer;" class="pricing_button">Purchase</a>
```